# Pause AnimationTimer JavaFX

Tags: animation, javafx

I am making a game right now using JavaFX. I was just wondering how can I pause the Animation timer. I what to press a key on the keyboard and the timer pauses and if pressed again it will resume. Is it possible to do so? Thanks in advance.

I have tried using timer.stop() and timer.start() again after but the timer only stops and never start again.

```
gameScene.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent t) {
            if(t.getCode()== KeyCode.ESCAPE)
            {
                if(!pause){
                    pause = true;
                    timer.start();
                }
                if(pause){
                    pause = false;
                    timer.stop();
                }

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Maintain a reference to the [`AnimationTimer`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html) and invoke `#start()` and `#stop()` as appropriate. If there's some specific issue you're having, please [edit] your question to provide a [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using consecutive `if` statements where if the first one executes then the second one *will* execute, no exceptions. Take a look at your code:

```java
if(!pause){
    pause = true;
    timer.start();
}
if(pause){
    pause = false;
    timer.stop();
}
```

When `pause` is false the first `if` block is executed which sets `pause` to true and starts the timer. This makes the condition of the second `if` block evaluate to true, which leads to `pause` be set back to false and the timer being stopped. In other words, you're starting and then *immediately* stopping the timer. Note it doesn't matter what the initial value of `pause` is, since `pause` will be false after the above code runs at least once (because of the second `if` block).

Since there's only two possible states for a boolean, and you want to toggle between the two, just use a simple if-else:

```java
if (paused) {
  paused = false;
  timer.start();
} else {
  paused = true;
  timer.stop();
}
```